# Facebook Like Box Won't Appear (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, twitter-bootstrap

So this has been driving me crazy, I've been searching similar questions but they all have solutions that seem not to work for me. I am trying to add a like box to my bootstrap website, but it won't appear. I am using the HTML5 version of the widget but have tried others to no avail, have this after my body tag:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "js/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I made a local verison of all.js since GET was failing to retrieve it from the Facebook servers, even after I uninstalled Ghostery.

Next, I added my like box using:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="MYSITEURL" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

With my actual URL of course, and no go, no matter how I arrange the code in a div by itself or anything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're testing the site on a local server, so all you need to do is add `"https:"` to this line:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

Like this:

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is related to Bootstrap. See http://bootply.com/94974, this use the same code as you do and works well.

Note in your example code `js.src = "js/all.js#xfbml=1";` refers to a local all.js where something like `//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js` will be needed.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me? Even copying that code directly, modifying it to fit my document and everything. I'm completely lost as to why this isn't working.

Comment: how do you load the code? For example in the body or in a modal? Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905807/how-can-i-list-two-linkedin-follow-buttons-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown/17052192 and http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties

Answer (score 0):

It works without problem. Need to be sure the referred fanpage (data-href) is a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

It can be FB page permissions setup issue. If the page visibility is restricted for audience from specific location(s), then the likebox doesn't appear.